# remove spaces in every where in the string python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below string

```
 a = " Get a Pen"
```

Code:

```
 if a.lower().strip() == "get a pen"
     print "removed white spaces"
```

## need help to achieve remove all spaces in the string

```
 if a.lower.().strip() =="getapen" # which is the easiest way remove all spaces
      print "remove all spaces in the string"
```

Comment: `a.replace(' ', '')` or `''.join(c for c in a if c != ' ')`

Comment: strip only removes trailing and leading spaces

Comment: @ChristianDean which one of `replace()` or `join()` is more optimised? I know that `join()` runs in linear time, but what about `replace()`?

Comment: @SamChats It also would work in linear time. But for simple cases such as this, `replace()` would probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

As @ChristianDean pointed out, do

```
if a.lower().replace(' ', '') == 'getapen':
    print "remove all spaces in the string"
```